# Full List of All VersionOne Asset Types and their 1 letter abbreviation?

Tags: versionone

Is there a full list of version one asset types and abbrevations?

The documentation contains a list of assets: https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Platform_Concepts/Asset_Type

But it is missing the "issue" asset type that is very apparently there (https://www14.v1host.com/v1sdktesting/Default.aspx?menu=IssuesProductPlanningPage&feat-nav=-m1 - admin/admin). Also, the list does not have the 1 letter abbreviation.

Is there a way to query the API to get all the asset types and their 1 letter abbreviation?

Answer (score 1):

The VersionOne metadata is found here

http://YourVersionOne/meta.v1?xsl=api.xsl.

This will show you the metadata for your entire VersionOne instance including custom fields.  You can also select individual assets such Issue like this

http://YourVersionOne/meta.v1/Issue?xsl=api.xsl.

The style at the end makes it look clean in your browser.

There is no way to see the prefix (which can be more than 1 char) in the metadata but if you have a particular asset that you would like to know the 1 char prefix for,  look in your data and examine the **Number** attribute.  Here is a way to see the **Issue** asset

http://YourVersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Issue?sel=Number,AssetType.

You can repeat this for any asset that you would like to know the "prefix" for.  Here is a snippet of the output

```
<Asset href="/MyVersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Issue/1204" id="Issue:1204">   
    <Attribute name="Number">I-01001</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="AssetType">Issue</Attribute>
</Asset>
```

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP GET to the `<versionone-url>/meta.v1` endpoint should give you information about every AssetType in the system. I am not sure about the 1 letter abbreviation. In regards to a story are you referring to the S in `S`-0110